# An item with the same key has already been added to dictionary

Tags: vb.net

When running the below code I sometimes get the following error:

```
 System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Interfaces.InterfaceBase.GetSettings()
```

I am using the below code:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dsData.Tables("tblData").Rows  
    If InterfaceSettings.ContainsKey(dr("SettingsName").ToString.Trim) = False Then  
        InterfaceSettings.Add(dr("SettingsName").ToString.Trim, dr("SettingsValue").ToString.Trim)  
    End If  
Next
```

I have no duplicates in the database table. Any idea why this would ever fail?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are no duplicates in dr("SettingsName") and that none of them are null or String.Empty? If you had one or two items which are empty it would add in a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exception you have posted is not related to the code. If you look at the stack trace, you will see the exception is generated by a call to Dictionary.Insert, not Dictionary.Add. I would search the remainder of the procedure to see where you are calling Dictionary Insert.

Comment: @competent_tech - `.Add` calls `.Insert` internally  :  `public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
            Insert(key, value, true);
        }` --- `Insert` is the internal private method

Comment: @J...: I understand that, but unless the compiler optimizes the generated code to remove the reference to Add, which I don't believe is the case, the stack trace will always include the call to add first:    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)

Comment: @competent_tech - no, not if the exception was raised through a call to a method in another class.  In this case his code has called `.GetSettings()`, inside of which is the code that adds to the dictionary.  It's not possible to call `.Insert` in user code - it's a private method in TDictionary and is not accessible.

Comment: Is the exception definitely thrown on the line you've put in your post?  Is `InterfaceBase` a class you have written or does it come from something else?  If you have written it, can you show us the full code of `GetSettings()`?  If it is a library you are using - which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

How does a duplicate key exception occur when code is checking for the key before attempting to add it?

I think the answer is that the code is shared. The error occurs when a thread checks the condition and is about to update the dictionary but is interrupted by another thread which then updates the dictionary and then the original thread does the same resulting in a duplicate key exception.