# VB.Net Merge multiple pdfs into one and export

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have to merge multiple PDFs into a single PDF.

I am using the iText.sharp library, and collect converted the code and tried to use it (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925616/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-generated-in-run-time/15945467?noredirect=1#comment53906468_15945467))
The actual code is in C# and I converted that to VB.NET.

```
 Private Function MergeFiles(ByVal sourceFiles As List(Of Byte())) As Byte()
    Dim mergedPdf As Byte() = Nothing
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Using document As New Document()
            Using copy As New PdfCopy(document, ms)
                document.Open()
                For i As Integer = 0 To sourceFiles.Count - 1
                    Dim reader As New PdfReader(sourceFiles(i))
                    ' loop over the pages in that document
                    Dim n As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
                    Dim page As Integer = 0
                    While page < n
                        page = page + 1
                        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page))
                    End While
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        mergedPdf = ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

I am now getting the following error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I did some debugging and have tracked the problem down to the following lines:

```
copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader,
copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page)))
```

Why is this error happening?

Comment: a down vote without any comment

Comment: Many hours': for finding solution for the error

Comment: @Vikky have you put break points in the code..? and stepped through the code..?

Comment: @Vikky go to this link and convert the C# code from the link that `Bob` posted to VB http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @Vikky Ah yes, see my answer and tell me if that works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An item with the same key has already been added to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599872/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-to-dictionary).

Comment: @Vikky Your question is a duplicate, and as far as we can tell you haven't tried debugging it for more than five minutes. Remember that the objective of Stack Overflow is to be a repository for programming questions & answers; your question doesn't help with that and this means that it should be duplicate-signposted.

Comment: this is your assumption, go to the hyperlink where the original author of answer asked me to post as separate question, its only me who knows how much time i have wasted in debugging and overcoming the error. According to you, you are "VB.NET braniac", and i will be always a keen learner.  Thanks for giving your valuable time in solving my query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91878/discussion-between-bob-and-vikky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a console that monitors individual folders in a designated folder then needs to merge all of the pdf's in that folder into a single pdf. I pass an array of file paths as strings and the output file i would like.

This is the function i use.

```
Public Shared Function MergePdfFiles(ByVal pdfFiles() As String, ByVal outputPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim pdfCount As Integer = 0     'total input pdf file count
    Dim f As Integer = 0    'pointer to current input pdf file
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing
    Dim pageCount As Integer = 0
    Dim pdfDoc As iTextSharp.text.Document = Nothing    'the output pdf document
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = Nothing
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = Nothing

    Dim page As PdfImportedPage = Nothing
    Dim rotation As Integer = 0

    Try
        pdfCount = pdfFiles.Length
        If pdfCount > 1 Then
            'Open the 1st item in the array PDFFiles
            fileName = pdfFiles(f)
            reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileName)
            'Get page count
            pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages

            pdfDoc = New iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1), 18, 18, 18, 18)

            writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))


            With pdfDoc
                .Open()
            End With
            'Instantiate a PdfContentByte object
            cb = writer.DirectContent
            'Now loop thru the input pdfs
            While f < pdfCount
                'Declare a page counter variable
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                'Loop thru the current input pdf's pages starting at page 1
                While i < pageCount
                    i += 1
                    'Get the input page size
                    pdfDoc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                    'Create a new page on the output document
                    pdfDoc.NewPage()
                    'If it is the 1st page, we add bookmarks to the page
                    'Now we get the imported page
                    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
                    'Read the imported page's rotation
                    rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i)
                    'Then add the imported page to the PdfContentByte object as a template based on the page's rotation
                    If rotation = 90 Then
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
                    ElseIf rotation = 270 Then
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Width + 60, -30)
                    Else
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End While
                'Increment f and read the next input pdf file
                f += 1
                If f < pdfCount Then
                    fileName = pdfFiles(f)
                    reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileName)
                    pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages
                End If
            End While
            'When all done, we close the document so that the pdfwriter object can write it to the output file
            pdfDoc.Close()
            result = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: FYI: Possible duplicate of [An item with the same key has already been added to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599872/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-to-dictionary).

Comment: it works like a charm @Sean Wessell. Thanks for such a great help

Comment: and again here i am not able to understand the co-relation for duplicacy

Comment: Down-voting because you are misleading people into thinking this is the way to merge documents (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552775). As explained in [chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book, you are throwing away all interactivity. If the original files contain links, annotations,... they will all be gone after merging. Because of answers like yours, many developers do the wrong thing (and it's so tiring for us having to explain over and over again what they are doing wrong).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - It depends on the requirements of the merge system.  If the PDF files do not contain any interactive content, links, annotations, etc., or those elements are unimportant within the context of the merged document, then, if this code succeeds in merging multiple PDF files, it's an acceptable answer.  The only thing I would suggest for improving the answer would be to mention the possibility/likelihood of functionality loss using this method.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat If you add the likelihood of functionality loss, also mention that each page is added to the new document as a Form XObject. When this operation is repeated many times (which is the case in some projects I helped debug), you end up with XObjects referring to XObjects referring to XObjects. Too many nested XObjects can cause performance problems and even hit implementation limits of the viewer that make the viewer fail to render the document or even crash.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - Absolutely.  The answer *should* include *any* possible negative side-effects that might result, although we all know that we don't always get (or know of) such problems listed. I've read a part of the sample chapter you've linked, and, as I'm interested in the subject of how best to merge PDF files, I'll probably be looking more closely into that.  However, if the code above works for a "proof of concept" solution, I'll probably start there.

Comment: @Sean Wessell your code works great, with one exception for me. When my app creates a pdf and then merges other pdf's to it, then the app creates the same pdf again I get an error that the file is being used in another process. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

the code that was marked correct does not close all the file streams therefore the files stay open within the app and you wont be able to delete unused PDFs within your project

This is a better solution:

```
Public Sub MergePDFFiles(ByVal outPutPDF As String) 

    Dim StartPath As String = FileArray(0) ' this is a List Array declared Globally
    Dim document = New Document()
    Dim outFile = Path.Combine(outPutPDF)' The outPutPDF varable is passed from another sub this is the output path
    Dim writer = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))

    Try

        document.Open()
        For Each fileName As String In FileArray

            Dim reader = New PdfReader(Path.Combine(StartPath, fileName))

            For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages

                Dim page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
                writer.AddPage(page)

            Next i

            reader.Close()

        Next

        writer.Close()
        document.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'catch a Exception if needed

    Finally

        writer.Close()
        document.Close()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: **a** Closing the `Document` implicitly closes the `PdfWriter`, it does not make sense to close the writer explicitly.  **b** If you close the `Document` in the `Finally` block anyways, it does not make sense also closing it in the `Try` block. **c** If you want to make sure to close everything, why don't you explicitly close the file stream? One can after all disable the implicit closing of the file stream in the writer...

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm pretty late to the party, but after reading the comments from **@BrunoLowagie**, I wanted to see if I could put something together myself that uses the examples from his linked sample chapter.  It's probably overkill, but I put together some code that merges multiple PDFs into a single file that I posted on the **Code Review SE** site (the post, [VB.NET - Error Handling in Generic Class for PDF Merge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186724/vb-net-error-handling-in-generic-class-for-pdf-merge), contains the full class code).  It only merges PDF files right now, but I'm planning on adding methods for additional functionality later.

The "master" method (towards the end of the `Class` block in the linked post, and also posted below for reference) handles the actual merging of the PDF files, but the multiple overloads provide a number of options for how to define the list of original files. So far, I've included the following features:

- The methods return a `System.IO.FileInfo` object if the merge is successful.
- Provide a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object or a `System.String` identifying a path and it will collect all PDF files in that directory (including sub-directories if specified) to merge.
- Provide a `List(Of System.String)` or a `List(Of System.IO.FileInfo)` specifying the PDFs you want to merge.
- Identify how the PDFs should be sorted before the merge (especially useful if you use one of the `MergeAll` methods to get all PDF files in a directory).
- If the specified output PDF file already exists, you can specify whether or not you want to overwrite it. (*I'm considering adding the "ability" to automatically adjust the output PDF file's name if it already exists*).
- `Warning` and `Error` properties provide a way to get feedback in the calling method, whether or not the merge is successful.

Once the code is in place, it can be used like this:

```
Dim PDFDir As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Test Data\PDF\")
Dim ResultFile As IO.FileInfo = Nothing
Dim Merger As New PDFManipulator

ResultFile = Merger.MergeAll(PDFDir, "C:\Test Data\PDF\Merged.pdf", True, PDFManipulator.PDFMergeSortOrder.FileName, True)
```

Here is the "master" method.  As I said, it's probably overkill (and I'm *still* tweaking it some), but I wanted to do my best to try to make it work as effectively as possible.  Obviously it requires a Reference to the `itextsharp.dll` for access to the library's functions.

*I've commented out the references to the `Error` and `Warning` properties of the class for **this** post to help reduce any confusion.*

```
Public Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal OverwriteExistingPDF As Boolean, ByVal SortOrder As PDFMergeSortOrder) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim ResultFile As System.IO.FileInfo = Nothing
    Dim ContinueMerge As Boolean = True

    If OverwriteExistingPDF Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(OutputFileName) Then
            Try
                System.IO.File.Delete(OutputFileName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ContinueMerge = False

                'If Errors Is Nothing Then
                '    Errors = New List(Of String)
                'End If

                'Errors.Add("Could not delete existing output file.")

                Throw
            End Try
        End If
    End If

    If ContinueMerge Then
        Dim OutputPDF As iTextSharp.text.Document = Nothing
        Dim Copier As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy = Nothing
        Dim PDFStream As System.IO.FileStream = Nothing
        Dim SortedList As New List(Of System.IO.FileInfo)

        Try
            Select Case SortOrder
                Case PDFMergeSortOrder.Original
                    SortedList = PDFFiles
                Case PDFMergeSortOrder.FileDate
                    SortedList = PDFFiles.OrderBy(Function(f As System.IO.FileInfo) f.LastWriteTime).ToList
                Case PDFMergeSortOrder.FileName
                    SortedList = PDFFiles.OrderBy(Function(f As System.IO.FileInfo) f.Name).ToList
                Case PDFMergeSortOrder.FileNameWithDirectory
                    SortedList = PDFFiles.OrderBy(Function(f As System.IO.FileInfo) f.FullName).ToList
            End Select

            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(New IO.FileInfo(OutputFileName).DirectoryName) Then
                Try
                    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(New IO.FileInfo(OutputFileName).DirectoryName)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ContinueMerge = False

                    'If Errors Is Nothing Then
                    '    Errors = New List(Of String)
                    'End If

                    'Errors.Add("Could not create output directory.")

                    Throw
                End Try
            End If

            If ContinueMerge Then
                OutputPDF = New iTextSharp.text.Document
                PDFStream = New System.IO.FileStream(OutputFileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Copier = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(OutputPDF, PDFStream)

                OutputPDF.Open()

                For Each PDF As System.IO.FileInfo In SortedList
                    If ContinueMerge Then
                        Dim InputReader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing

                        Try
                            InputReader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PDF.FullName)

                            For page As Integer = 1 To InputReader.NumberOfPages
                                Copier.AddPage(Copier.GetImportedPage(InputReader, page))
                            Next page

                            If InputReader.IsRebuilt Then
                                'If Warnings Is Nothing Then
                                '    Warnings = New List(Of String)
                                'End If

                                'Warnings.Add("Damaged PDF: " & PDF.FullName & " repaired and successfully merged into output file.")
                            End If
                        Catch InvalidEx As iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException
                            'Skip this file
                            'If Errors Is Nothing Then
                            '    Errors = New List(Of String)
                            'End If

                            'Errors.Add("Invalid PDF: " & PDF.FullName & " not merged into output file.")
                        Catch FormatEx As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BadPdfFormatException
                            'Skip this file
                            'If Errors Is Nothing Then
                            '    Errors = New List(Of String)
                            'End If

                            'Errors.Add("Bad PDF Format: " & PDF.FullName & " not merged into output file.")
                        Catch PassworddEx As iTextSharp.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException
                            'Skip this file
                            'If Errors Is Nothing Then
                            '    Errors = New List(Of String)
                            'End If

                            'Errors.Add("Password-protected PDF: " & PDF.FullName & " not merged into output file.")
                        Catch OtherEx As Exception
                            ContinueMerge = False
                        Finally
                            If Not InputReader Is Nothing Then
                                InputReader.Close()
                                InputReader.Dispose()
                            End If
                        End Try
                    End If
                Next PDF
            End If
        Catch ex As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfException
            ResultFile = Nothing
            ContinueMerge = False

            'If Errors Is Nothing Then
            '    Errors = New List(Of String)
            'End If

            'Errors.Add("iTextSharp Error: " & ex.Message)

            If System.IO.File.Exists(OutputFileName) Then
                If Not OutputPDF Is Nothing Then
                    OutputPDF.Close()
                    OutputPDF.Dispose()
                End If

                If Not PDFStream Is Nothing Then
                    PDFStream.Close()
                    PDFStream.Dispose()
                End If

                If Not Copier Is Nothing Then
                    Copier.Close()
                    Copier.Dispose()
                End If

                System.IO.File.Delete(OutputFileName)
            End If

            Throw
        Catch other As Exception
            ResultFile = Nothing
            ContinueMerge = False

            'If Errors Is Nothing Then
            '    Errors = New List(Of String)
            'End If

            'Errors.Add("General Error: " & other.Message)

            If System.IO.File.Exists(OutputFileName) Then
                If Not OutputPDF Is Nothing Then
                    OutputPDF.Close()
                    OutputPDF.Dispose()
                End If

                If Not PDFStream Is Nothing Then
                    PDFStream.Close()
                    PDFStream.Dispose()
                End If

                If Not Copier Is Nothing Then
                    Copier.Close()
                    Copier.Dispose()
                End If

                System.IO.File.Delete(OutputFileName)
            End If

            Throw
        Finally
            If Not OutputPDF Is Nothing Then
                OutputPDF.Close()
                OutputPDF.Dispose()
            End If

            If Not PDFStream Is Nothing Then
                PDFStream.Close()
                PDFStream.Dispose()
            End If

            If Not Copier Is Nothing Then
                Copier.Close()
                Copier.Dispose()
            End If

            If System.IO.File.Exists(OutputFileName) Then
                If ContinueMerge Then
                    ResultFile = New System.IO.FileInfo(OutputFileName)

                    If ResultFile.Length <= 0 Then
                        ResultFile = Nothing

                        Try
                            System.IO.File.Delete(OutputFileName)
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Throw
                        End Try
                    End If
                Else
                    ResultFile = Nothing

                    Try
                        System.IO.File.Delete(OutputFileName)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Throw
                    End Try
                End If
            Else
                ResultFile = Nothing
            End If
        End Try
    End If

    Return ResultFile
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

Some may have to make a change to the code at "`writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))`" as `iTextSharp` may not support

Change to:

```
Dim fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(outputPath, IO.FileMode.Create)

writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)
```