# How do I concatenate pdf files using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

How do I concatenate (merge? append? I'm not sure which term is correct) two or more pdf files using vb.net? I currently have Visual Studio 2015 Community. I have no idea of the content of the files and just want to end up with one document containing one after the other of the documents being input. I'm very new to vb.net programming, and OO programming in general, so please be specific. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to this SO post [vb-net-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-one-and-export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043151/vb-net-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-one-and-export) It uses iTextSharp PDF library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple pdf files (generated in run time)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925616/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-generated-in-run-time)

Comment: In essence your question is asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource and, therefore, is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mkl I think the question meets the criteria of on-topic in the help center.  The wording you're paraphrasing was designed to discourage open-ended questions like, "What is the best library to do *X*?"  Instead OP has *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*.

Comment: @jih if you see our so, the natural answer would be (unless Microsoft recently introduced general purpose PDF support) that a specialized PDF library is required for that task. By the way, both your and haraman's comments point toward using such a library, by chance to the same... ;)